# tcpdump reports error in Docker container that's started with --privileged

Tags: docker

I made a packet-sending app image based on Ubuntu, and install `tcpdump`. When I start the container with `--privileged` and try to `tcpdump -i eth0`, it reports an error:

```
root@test:/home/test# docker run --rm -ti --privileged mytliulei/xfdsend /bin/bash
root@6199493fb2b9:/# tcpdump -i eth0
tcpdump: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

**But when I start the Docker container without `--privileged`, it is ok**. why?

```
root@test:/home/test# docker run --rm -ti  mytliulei/xfdsend /bin/bash
root@c7b7e2a9ec99:/# tcpdump -i eth0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

Docker version:

```
docker version 
Client version: 1.6.0
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 4749651
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.0
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 4749651
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Liu Lei <xxx@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y python \
    python-dev \
    tcpdump

RUN pip2 install scapy \
    && pip2 install rpyc \
    && pip2 install robotremoteserver \
    && pip2 install daemonocle
```

Answer (score 17):

I bumped into this error some days ago, the error seems to be related to:

https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5490

a workaround that worked for me is moving tcpdump:

(e.g. mv in tcpdump with dockerfile)

```
RUN apt-get -y install tcpdump
RUN mv /usr/sbin/tcpdump /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with tcpdump.

```
root@host:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# tcpdump -i eth0 'port 37'
tcpdump: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

It appears you can fix this with specifying the command to run explicitly in docker run

```
ubuntu@host:~ docker run -- tcpdump -i any 'port 37'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
12:57:55.247892 IP6 3000:200:199:219::81.59244 > 1000:12:12:219::7.time: UDP, length 0
```

37 for the timeserver. Use any other port/tcpdump arguments you need.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me, its same as first answer, just that you can do this inside docker if its already running.

```
root@249574360f0b:/# tcpdump
tcpdump: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

root@249574360f0b:/# mv /usr/sbin/tcpdump /usr/bin/tcpdump
root@249574360f0b:/# ln -s /usr/bin/tcpdump /usr/sbin/tcpdump
root@249574360f0b:/# tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on fpc1_int, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:51:22.274545 36:34:a2:0c:15:97 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype Unknown (0x8850), length 142:
        0x0000:  3100 000c 43df 0003 ffff ffff 0000 0010  1...C...........
        0x0010:  03e8 1388 05dc 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000  ................
        0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```